# Suggestions needed on SQL Server 2016 cursor code that is crashing my SSMS application

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am running SSMS on Windows 10 and when I get to this cursor code in my SP, it is crashing my SSMS app.

I have a TEMP table that I'm trying to update each numeric column using this cursor which looks like this:

[image]

I inherited the following cursor that is literally crashing SSMS on my desktop:

```
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
SELECT DISTINCT a.PolicyID, a.tenurestartyearmonth, a.TotalnMonthDurationDR 
FROM #Tenuretmp a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT policyid, MAX(TotalnMonthDurationDR) tot
    FROM #Tenuretmp
    GROUP BY PolicyID
    --ORDER BY PolicyID asc
) b 
ON a.PolicyID = b.PolicyID 
AND a.TotalnMonthDurationDR = b.tot
ORDER BY a.TenureStartyearmonth asc, a.PolicyID asc;

OPEN db_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @PolicyID, @tenurestartyearmonth, @TotalnMonthDurationDR

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    SELECT @i = 0, @columns = N'' --,  @one = N'';

        WHILE @i < @TotalnMonthDurationDR
        BEGIN
            SET @columns =  @columns + ',' + ' [' + cast((@i+1) as nvarchar) +  ']  =  [' + cast((@i+1) as nvarchar) +  '] + 1' SET @i = @i + 1;
        END

        SET @sql = 'Update #Survivaltmp SET ' + STUFF(@columns, 1, 1, '') + ' WHERE Vintageyearmonth =' + @tenurestartyearmonth + ''

        exec (@sql)

    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @PolicyID, @tenurestartyearmonth, @TotalnMonthDurationDR
END  

CLOSE db_cursor  
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

I would like to do an update as an alternative within the WHILE loop statement but cannot figure out how to use the result set.  I've not worked with cursors before and any suggestions/help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Check your event logs to see what the error is when SSMS "crashes".

Comment: Are all other "cursors" do not crash SSMS?

Comment: Did you try to see if using the CLI interface sqlcmd you can execute it till the end ? Sometimes SSMS is crashing weirdly when you have a lot of rows and columns in the result tab cause the graphic interface is using 32bit subsytem and cannot allocate more than 2GB of memory.
Eventually you can also try to set the result in text format as described here to avoid the heavy graphic rendering. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2874903

Comment: Thanks for all the replies.  I can't seem to find the SSMS crashes(3) in the event log on my Windows 10 box.  We don't have cursors that we're running in PROD. Person who wrote this is no longer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the cursor is updating the table for every iteration of the internal loop. Without data, I just took a guess at what it might look like based on what your code is doing. I cobbled the below together as a possible pointer to move away from the cursor option. It uses a CTE to cross apply your data to a tally table and then another CTE to take those results, pivot them into your number columns, and finally group them into tenurestartyearmonth and sum the number columns. Then we select from that second CTE.

I created a #SurvivalTemp table with the exact same structure (though Vintageyearmonth I left as tenurestartyearmonth) and ran your cursor against it with the same set of dummy data and returned the same results with both methods. You can test it here: https://rextester.com/PBZG61061

```
WITH spanBuilder AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT a.PolicyID, a.tenurestartyearmonth, a.TotalnMonthDurationDR, 
    c.*

    FROM #Tenuretmp a
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT policyid, MAX(TotalnMonthDurationDR) tot
        FROM #Tenuretmp
        GROUP BY PolicyID
        --ORDER BY PolicyID asc
    ) b 
    ON a.PolicyID = b.PolicyID 
    AND a.TotalnMonthDurationDR = b.tot
    CROSS apply (
    SELECT val = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1
        FROM (VALUES(0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0)) a(val)
        CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0)) b(val)
        CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0)) c(val)
        CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0)) d(val)) AS c
    WHERE c.val <= b.tot AND c.val >= 1
), spanFinder as
(
    SELECT tenurestartyearmonth, SUM([1]) AS [1], SUM([2]) AS [2], SUM([3]) AS [3], SUM([4]) AS [4], SUM([5]) AS [5],
     SUM([6]) AS [6], SUM([7]) AS [7], SUM([8]) AS [8], SUM([9]) AS [9],SUM([10]) AS  [10],
      SUM([11]) AS [11], SUM([12]) AS [12], SUM([13]) AS [13], SUM([14]) AS [14], SUM([15]) AS [15], SUM([16]) AS [16],
       SUM([17]) AS [17], SUM([18]) AS [18], SUM([19]) AS [19], SUM([20]) AS [20], SUM([21]) AS [21], SUM([22]) AS [22],
        SUM([23]) AS [23], SUM([24]) AS [24], SUM([25]) AS [25],SUM([26]) AS [26]
    FROM (SELECT policyid, tenurestartyearmonth, val FROM spanBuilder) AS SourceTable
    PIVOT
    (
    count(val) FOR val IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10],  [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20], [21], [22], [23], [24], [25],[26])) AS PivotTable
    GROUP BY PivotTable.tenurestartyearmonth
)

SELECT * FROM spanFinder
```

Updated version: https://rextester.com/PBZG61061

This uses not CTEs. Instead it uses another temp table to store the results of what was previously spanBuilder. That table is then used to generate the column information dynamically. This new example I added another record that goes out 45 months to demonstrate. I've also updated it to leave NULL instead of 0. It's still an INT, but I think datatype conversion is probably the easy part here.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colsDefined AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT DISTINCT a.PolicyID, a.tenurestartyearmonth, a.TotalnMonthDurationDR, 
c.*
INTO #spanBuilderTempTable
FROM #Tenuretmp a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT policyid, MAX(TotalnMonthDurationDR) tot
    FROM #Tenuretmp
    GROUP BY PolicyID
    --ORDER BY PolicyID asc
) b 
ON a.PolicyID = b.PolicyID 
AND a.TotalnMonthDurationDR = b.tot
CROSS apply (
SELECT val = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1
    FROM (VALUES(0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0)) a(val)
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0)) b(val)
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0)) c(val)
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0)) d(val)) AS c
WHERE c.val <= b.tot AND c.val >= 1


SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(c.val) 
        FROM #spanBuilderTempTable c
        GROUP BY c.val
        ORDER BY CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(c.val,'[',''),']','') AS INT)
        FOR XML PATH('') , TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'') 

SELECT @colsDefined = STUFF((SELECT ',' + 'iif(sum(' + QUOTENAME(c.val) + ')=0,NULL,sum(' + QUOTENAME(c.val) + ')) as ' + QUOTENAME(c.val) +''
    FROM #spanBuilderTempTable c
    GROUP BY c.val
    ORDER BY CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(c.val,'[',''),']','') AS INT)
    FOR XML PATH('') , TYPE
    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
,1,1,'') 

set @query = 'SELECT tenurestartyearmonth, ' + @colsDefined + ' from 
            (
                select tenurestartyearmonth
                    , val
                from #spanBuilderTempTable
           ) SourceTable
            pivot 
            (
                 count(val)
                for val in (' + @cols + ')
            ) PivotTable 
            GROUP BY PivotTable.tenurestartyearmonth'


EXEC(@query)
```

Comment: Question if you don't mind, as you could see the @columns are built dynamically and I will not know how many columns there will be in a given time period and I'm wondering how do I account for those in my SELECT in spanFinder as you have them defined individually?  Sorry but I've never done a cross apply.  Hope that makes sense.  Thanks for your help and time.

Comment: Is #survivaltmp built dynamically? If you have any idea of the possible max month duration you could predefine it based on that. Currently, if a period only has, say, entries for 2 months, the other columns will show as 0 for that period. If we're completely unsure of how many potential max columns we could have, we'll need to build out the schema and pivot dynamically. That won't be super fun :)

Comment: Yes, #Survivaltmp is built dynamically.  I do have the max month duration value for each month. Also, the customer does not want 0 in the other columns but wants empty strings which is what the #Survivaltmp table has before it is populated.

Comment: I've updated it to dynamically generate the columns.

Comment: OMG, that's awesome!  I'll try that.  Thanks so much for your time and help.  I'll let you know shortly.  Thanks again.

Comment: I'm getting an invalid column name 'val' When I execute the code.

Comment: Strange. It's working in the link I added and in mine. Does it say which instance of 'val' it's having issues with?

Comment: Yes.  Sorry I missed something in the code.  That got it.  Thank you for all your time and help.  It is appreciated and I've learned a lot.